# Что не так при установке ENUM NULL MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне правильно организовать таблицу ENUM, в которой обычно перечисляются платежная система при зачислении средств, а при их расходе не указывается (NULL)
Сейчас у меня примерно такой вариант:

```
ALTER TABLE 'payments_history' CHANGE 'payment_system' 'payment_system' 
ENUM('cash','tinkoff','qiwi','yoomoney','webmoney') NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что я ошибаюсь или заблуждаюсь, т.к. phpmyadmin выдает мне ошибку следующего содержания:

> «Data truncated for column 'payment_system' at row 9...»

Подскажите правильный вариант.

Comment: хотелось бы всё-таки не "примерно такой вариант" (синтаксически ошибочный), а минимальный воспроизводимый. С ходу предположу, что таблица у вас не пустая и ошибку вызывают существующие в таблице данные, не укладывающиеся в перечисленные варианты

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dba05/1 вот пример. Отсюда возникает вопрос, а как правильно, добавить в enum значение = "" или при генерации значений пустое поле input должно преобразовываться в NULL?

Comment: Если всё-таки перевести сообщение об ошибке, то оно говорит, что при изменении свойств поля некоторые уже имеющиеся в таблице значения будут урезаны/усечены. В данном конкретном случае это почти наверняка наличие значения, которое отсутствует в списке-определении допустимых значений типа. Выполните `SELECT DISTINCT payment_system FROM payments_history;`. PS. Конкретно этот запрос должен привести к другой ошибке - ошибке синтаксиса. Вследствие использования неправильных кавычек. А принципиально к запросу претензий нет: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/680e2c